# Converting list of dictionaries to list of objects in python

Tags: python, dictionary, object, oop

Let's say I have list of dictionaries of Persons as followed -

```
[
 {
    'Name' : 'Michael',
    'Age'  : '19',
    'Role' : 'Manager'
 },
 {
    'Name' : 'Josh',
    'Age'  : '20',
    'Role' : 'Student'
 }
]
```

And so on...
I get this data from an API and want to make every dictionary as an object of class Person.
I'm having a hard time coding it in python and don't even know where to start? should I iterate the list with a for loop and then construct each variable one by one?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just loop though the dict, convert it to an object, and put it back.

Comment: Could you share your `Person` class?

Comment: I don't have a class yet, I have the data I shared from API, bichanna can you give an example please?  thanks!!

Comment: If you don't have a class, then how do you plan to create instances of it? If you don't know how to write classes at all, then *that is the real problem you need to solve first*, and it's one that you solve by *reading and following a tutorial*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of `Person` class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, role):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.role = role
    # other methods
```

Loop through the list of data and convert it to `Person` object

```
new_lst = []
for i in lst: # lst is the list that contains the data
    person = Person(i["Name"], i["Age"], i["Role"])
    new_lst.append(person)
```

Comment: that's a list example and I have a list of dictionaries, but ty anyway:)